# Как писать текст в обычных тегах и зачем?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У редактора статей вк поля для ввода текста являются тегами `h1` и `p`. Как это самому сделать и для чего это? 
Нужно самому слушать на элементах события клавиш, а также на телефоне самому открывать клавиатуру, чтобы вводить текст и слушать событие взаимодействия с клавиатурой, чтобы вводить в эти теги?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для тега установите атрибут `contenteditable="true"`.
Зачем? Возможность редактирования и форматирования текста на странице, который потом можно отправить на сервер.

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true">Меня можно редактировать</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ [@xydope](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/368113/xydope), чтобы не добавлять атрибут к элементу через html, можно поменять через js так: `elem.contentEditable = 'true'`
С помощью свойства `elem.isContentEditable` можно узнать, редактируемый это элемент или нет
Можно слушать у редактируемого элемента, когда поле ввода активно и не активно с помощью слушателей `focus` и `blur` соответственно

```js
elem.contentEditable = 'true';
if (elem.isContentEditable) {
  elem1.innerHTML = `${elem.id} - редактируемый элемент`;
}

elem.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  elem2.innerHTML = `${elem.id} - в фокусe`;
});

elem.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  elem2.innerHTML = `${elem.id} - не в фокусе`;
});
```

```css
#elem {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="elem"></h1>
<div id="elem1"></div>
<div id="elem2"></div>
```